# Physical data location of MapR DB table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, mapr

I created a table in MapR DB and loaded some raw data into it using hbase shell. Where can i find this data on MapR file system ? like hive data is stored in warehouse directory similarly how does MapR DB works?

Or is there any other concept behind storing MapR DB data?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the HBase shell to create a MapR DB table, then your table has a path. That path is where the table resides in the file system.

Comment: Agreed that we need to provide path while creating MapR db table but when i load data into table then size of that file should change which looks like does not happen. But in case of Hbase,data is distributed across regions, and data increases then region splitting happens. How things are managed in MapR DB table?

Comment: @Shashi - Tables appear in the file system, but they are not files, per se. Not all file system operations work against tables: http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Filesystem+Operations+on+MapR-DB+Tables